# phpPgAdmin access denied for remote access on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, postgresql, ubuntu, phppgadmin

I've looked at quite a few answers for this, but all seem apparently out of date. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache 2.4.7. My /etc/apache2/conf.d/phppgadmin file looks like this:

```
Alias /phppgadmin /usr/share/phppgadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phppgadmin>

DirectoryIndex index.php
AllowOverride all

order deny,allow
#deny from all
#allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
Require all granted

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
  php_flag track_vars On
  #php_value include_path .
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  <IfModule mod_actions.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
      AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
      Action application/x-httpd-php /cgi-bin/php
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
      AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
      Action application/x-httpd-php /cgi-bin/php
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

</Directory>
```

Also have a file 000-default in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled while looks like:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpPgAdmin">
        AuthUserFile /etc/phpPgAdmin/.htpasswd
        AuthName "Restricted Area"
        AuthType Basic
        require valid-user
</Directory>
```

And I've modified /etc/phppgadmin/.htpasswd appropriately.

Nonetheless, when I try to log into it remotely I get a 403: Forbidden error.

Any ideas? Further, could this error be imposed by the type of network I'm on? (it's a campus network).

Comment: `/etc/phpPgAdmin/.htpasswd` is not the same as `/etc/phppgadmin/.htpasswd`. Unix paths are case sensitive.

Comment: thanks! i have corrected this, but i'm still getting the 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: look at the apache error log for the root cause of the 403 (and remember that changes to apache conf files are ignored until you reload apache)

Answer (score 0):

Try is

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/conf.d/phppgadmin /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phppgadmin.conf
```

Restart httpd2 (Apache)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

For Ubuntu 14.04